# No synchronized non-blocking read method in basic Stream/StreamReader class

Tags: c#, networking, stream, bouncycastle, system.io.file

Recently I'm trying some .Net.Sockets secured networking by using BouncyCastle library.
The TlsStream class in BouncyCastle inherits the original `Stream` (not `NetworkStream`), and `StreamReader`/`StreamWriter` seem to be a convenient way for read/write.

Since I tend to use 1 thread for 1 end(server or client) to handle both `read` and `write` :

```cs
void CommunicationLoop() // Loops in Thread A
{
    while (true)
    {
        ReadFromStream(); // If data available. It always hangs/blocks here(if there's no data to be read.)
        WriteToStream(); // If user input something.
    }
}

void ReadFromStream()
{
    String line;
    while ( StreamReader.Peek() > -1 )
// Or ((line = StreamReader.ReadLine()) != null) / (Stream.Read(buff, 0, buff.Length) > 0)
// or any synchronized Readxxx() methods.
// It always hangs/blocks here(if there's no data to be read.)
    {
        line = StreamReader.ReadLine();   
        Console.WriteLine($"Received: {line}");
    }
}

void WriteToStream()
{
    //...
}
```

I did a lot of research, everyone suggests to use async method to solve the problem.

- **I would like to know that, is there really no official method/function to check if there is data to be read in `StreamReader`/`Stream`, if no data then skip(instead of hanging there waiting for the input, like the `NetworkStream.DataAvailable`)?**
- Also, if the the communication for 1 connection is not heavy, isn't using 1 thread dealing with both read/write in server side (there might be multiple connections from MANY CLIENTS to ONE SERVER) more efficient(saves resource)?

Thanks.

Comment: You can use the [StreamReader.ReadAsync()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader.readasync?view=netcore-3.1) method and pass a `CancellationToken` to it

Comment: @MindSwipe so there really no synchronized read method right? I have to use async and check timeout/cancellation anyway?

Comment: There is the `StreamReader.Read()` method, which you can use if you desperately need it to be sync

Comment: @MindSwipe As what I tried, StreamReader.Read() still blocks.

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to know that, is there really no official method/function to check if there is data to be read in StreamReader/Stream

Check the documentation for [StreamReader](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader?view=netcore-3.1). As far as I can see there is no way to check for waiting data without using the async methods.

> Also, if the the communication for 1 connection is not heavy, isn't using 1 thread dealing with both read/write in server side (there might be multiple connections from MANY CLIENTS to ONE SERVER) more efficient(saves resource)

This should not be more efficient than using the async methods. Consider the case where all clients are idle. Your method would use 1 thread per client. Using async methods would not use any threads. Assuming the async methods use non-blocking IO in the backend. It is possible the sync methods have slightly lower overhead since they can do the synchronization in the kernel rather than in .Net, but I think this would need benchmarking to verify.

Is there some specific reason you do not want to use the async methods?

Comment: I was digging some game networking things, and people say 1 thread for both read and write is better than creating thread for each of them, because when many clients(let's say 1000 or more) connect to server, the threads doubles if you create 2 threads for every client. My thought async(Task things) method is like a temporary thread work, so for many non-idling clients(I'm not there yet), creating async task 10 times/sec for 1 client could be expensive.

Comment: For frequent network communication, if I have to do it asynchronous, instead of using async method, I think I better create 1 thread for read, and 1 for write, right?

Comment: My concern is how heavy **using a async method/creating a task** is, on a  **10~30 times/sec per client, 1000 clients level.** compare to **creating 1 more thread to handle read**

Comment: @tomBlooz Async methods are not equivalent to threads. When you run "ReadAsync" it will just create an non-blocking IO operation in the OS and return, in effect freeing the running thread to return to the threadpool. When the IO operation completes a threadpool thread will be used to continue where the first thread left of. Creating a task will have some overhead, but it should be fairly small. A major reason for introducing it was webservers handling many requests efficiently, a similar scenario to yours.

Comment: Thank you Jonas, I'm gonna try the async way, even still, I hope Stream and StreamReader can have the ```Network.DataAvailable``` like feature, which gives developer a choice :P.